# Python: How to plot an array of y values for one x value in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to plot an array of temperatures for different location during one day in python and want it to be graphed in the format (time, temperature_array). I am using matplotlib and currently only know how to graph 1 y value for an x value.

The temperature code looks like this:
`Temperatures = [[Temp_array0] [Temp_array1] [Temp_array2]...]`, where each numbered array corresponds to that time and the temperature values in the array are at different latitudes and longitudes.

Comment: Just do a second call to `.plot()` with a different set of `y` values with the same `x` values? What is your code? You can do multiple `plt.plot()` calls before `plt.show()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(times, temperatures, 'ro')
plt.axis([min(times)-1, max(times)+1,
          min(temperatures)-1, max(temperatures)+1])
plt.show()
```

It should make a dot plot of temperatures over times.

Comment: plt.plot still will have problems because temperatures is an array of arrays (based on latitude and longitude) so they have different first dimensions

Comment: Could you edit your question to show what format the temperatures array is? I don't quite get what you mean, but I feel like a list comprehension should get you the temperatures as a list of floats.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply repeat the X values which are common for y values

Suppose
`[x,x,x,x],[y1,y2,y3,y4]`